# Elevation in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, border, shadow, elevation

Here is my style defined in the React-Native screen. I have used the `elevation`
property to achieve a box-shadow. But it's not working properly.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
scrollContainer: {
    flex: 1,
},
container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    padding: 2
},
box: {
    margin: 8,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2 - 18,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2 - 18,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
    borderLeftWidth: 1,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderTopColor: 'black',
    borderBottomEndRadius : 8,
    borderTopStartRadius: 8,
    borderTopEndRadius: 8,
    borderBottomStartRadius: 8,
    borderBottomLeftRadius:8,
    borderBottomRightRadius:8,
    elevation: 5
},
navBar:{
    backgroundColor: "#000",
}
});
```

I have also tried using box-shadow but the same problem arises.

Comment: Have you tried specifing `shadowColor: Colors.BLACK,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 8 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.16,
    shadowRadius: 16`? Values are clearly random :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try to add following properties to the `styles.box`. You could change the values for better results.

```js
// ...
box: {
  // ...
  shadowColor: '#000',
  shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
  shadowOpacity: 0.5,
  shadowRadius: 2,
  elevation: 2,
},
// ...
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use below code

```
          height: 150,
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          elevation: 5,
          shadowColor: '#000',
          shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 0},
          shadowOpacity: 0.1,
          shadowRadius: 5,
```

Answer (score 1):

After little investigation, I found the working solution and here it is. There is a broad discussion over this problem on the [github issue](https://github.com/timomeh/react-native-material-bottom-navigation/issues/8).

```js
box: {
    margin: 8,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 2,
}
```

rather only using elevation property. Also, make sure you give the proper margin to the box for proper spacing. I was lacking the margin in my case. Hope it's useful findings to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this style in your View

```
 headerstyle:{
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 2,
    alignSelf: 'stretch'
},
```

Comment: shadow properties has not effect except elevation and shadowColor

Answer (score 1):

I created this when I was having issues. Since then I have been using it in my every project. It works well in all of my projects unless the client wants something different.

Just copy and paste this and change the values in elevation & height or weight of **shadowOffset** as per your requirement.

```
 shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: 2,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.21,
shadowRadius: 6.65,
elevation: 6,
```

},

Answer (score 0):

```
chip: {
    padding: 10,
    height: 40,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    elevation: 3,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  }
```

Comment: Please add explanations.